# Почему код выдаёт такую ошибку?

Tags: python

Почему код выдаёт такую ошибку?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "путь к боту", line 226, in
bot.run(info.token)
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'run'
```

Я понимаю что дело в самом объявлении `bot`. Но как можно по другому объявить, если у меня так:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Comment: нет, дело не в объявлении. Дело в том, что у bot нет свойства/функции run. Это как если создать объект Книга со свойствами Автор и ЦветОбложки, а потом пытаться обратиться к свойству Язык, которого нет.

Comment: А как тогда это исправить? До этого же всё работало хорошо.

Comment: Не обращаться к аттрибуту run, например. До чего "до этого"?

Comment: Это похоже на абсолютно валидное действие. У вас по пути в коде в переменную `bot` ничего больше не присваивается? А то создавали объект `Bot` из модуля `commands`, а когда дело дошло до вызова `run` там внезапно оказался объект типа `Command`. Прочитайте, пожалуйста, внимательно свой код или дополните вопрос минимальным воспроизводимым примером?

Comment: Ошибку исправил, я просто забыл что дополнительно создал команду у самого бота bot - которая бы выводила информацию о нём.